# Go: Pointer to type is incompatible with interface

Tags: go

I'm not sure how to formulate the question properly. I have 2 go code snippets that should do the exact same thing but apparently they don't, since one works and the other doesn't (doesn't compile)

```
func writeSomething(writer *io.Writer) {
}

func main() {
    file, _ := os.Create("error.log")
    var logWriter io.Writer = file
    writeSomething(&logWriter)

}

func main2() {
    file, _ := os.Create("error.log")
    writeSomething(&file)

}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dro4jowWZcw)

main() works and main2() doesn't.

> prog.go:20:17: cannot use &file (type **os.File) as type *io.Writer in argument to writeSomething:
>       *io.Writer is pointer to interface, not interface

The only difference is that I used an intermediate variable but I'm not doing any pointer referencing or dereferencing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Error message is exact. Just remove indirection in function signature func writeSomething(writer io.Writer) you need not it any case

Comment: Ok thanks, that works. But I would still be interested why the first version works even though it does the sam thing

Comment: In `main` you convert `file` to interface `io.Writer` and then pass `writeSomething` a pointer to the interface which is just what `writeSomething` expects.

Comment: In `main2` you have a pointer to `os.File` and then pass a pointer to that pointer to `writeSomething`. Go cannot convert that to a pointer to interface `io.Writer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use pointers to interfaces, it is a bad practice in Go.
And about code that doesn't compile - when you create an intermediate variable `logWriter` you allocate an interface variable, that has its own allocated memory to describe what it stores (actual type) and a reference to the actual structure.
That is why `&logWriter` and `&file` have different types.
But as I sad previously, you should not use pointers to interfaces, just use interface type and do not get address of interface type variable.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. I obviously have not yet fully understood how interfaces in go work.
Coming from C++ and Java something of type io.Writer does look a lot like an object and I didn't want to pass it around by value.